# Why is the usercontrol on the toolbox grayed out when the usercontrol and form are the same name but different namespace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-controls

When looking at the form designer of a form with the same name as your usercontrol, the usercontrol will not show up in the toolbox. It is actually on the toolbox and visible but grayed out with the "Show All" checked on the toolbox. While the form and usercontrol have the same name, they are in different namespaces.

Can anyone explain what the conflict is or is this a bug in Visual Studio 2010?

To reproduce (C#):

1. Create a new Winforms project
2. Create a folder in the project called "Forms"
3. Create a folder in the project called "UserControls"
4. Under "UserControls", add the following new UserControls "AppleDetail" and "OrangeDetail"
5. Under "Forms", add the following new forms "Test" and "OrangeDetail"
6. Build the project
7. Open the form designer for "Test", both usercontrols should be visible in the toolbox
8. Open the form designer for "OrangeDetail", only the "AppleDetail" usercontrol will be visible/enabled in the toolbox